# How can I colour boxes in Gviz AnnotationTrack in R?

Tags: r, bioconductor, gviz

I'm learning the Gviz bioconductor package, I generate a plot as follows:

```
library(Gviz)
track <- AnnotationTrack(start=c(1,5,7), end=c(2,6,10), strand=c('*','*','*'), stacking="dense", showFeatureId=TRUE, id=c('red','blue', 'red'))
pdf(file=paste("test","pdf", sep="."))
plotTracks(track)
dev.off()
```

`test.pdf` looks like this: [image]

However, what I want is for the boxes to be coloured rather than labelled with the colour word, how to do this?

Note that my real example is much more complex than this.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Did you try the `fill` argument?

Something like this:

```
track <- AnnotationTrack(start=c(1,5,7), end=c(2,6,10), strand=c('*','*','*'), stacking="dense", showFeatureId=TRUE, id=c('red','blue', 'red'), fill=c('red','blue', 'red'))
```

Comment: Thanks, seems to work, can't believe I missed that! What colours are accepted as arguments for `fill`?

Comment: Probably all colors, [here](http://sape.inf.usi.ch/quick-reference/ggplot2/colour) a list of color names.

Comment: @Chris_Rands see `?plotTracks` for the options accepted by `plotTracks` which will then refer you to `?settings` for the various things you can tweak (long, long documentation). Finally, `availableDisplayPars(track)` will show you what you can set for `track`.